# Real time data pipe lines to NoSql dbs in hadoop

Tags: cassandra, hbase, apache-flink, apache-beam, flume

I am working to build real time streaming applications in hadoop and I have experimented the below technologies to push data to hbase but I am looking for some more details on the technologies available

1. Spark Streaming - Uses micro batching
2. Kafka Connect - no connectors available
3. Nifi - Seems working but still it is pushing data as batches.

Is there any other technology that is perfect for pushing data to Hbase at real time for publishing the real time dash boards.

that guarantee exactly one semantics,avoids batching, and is real time to push data to any nosql databases and open source?

It seems **flink, splunk, flume, beam** are some technologies that are available to be experimented,little insights on these technologies with **any nosql databases** would be a great help.

Comment: Note that NiFi allows you to set Batch Size to 1 if needed.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use **Spark Structured Streaming**.

Internally Structured Streaming queries are also processed using a micro-batch processing engine, but with end-to-end latencies as low as **100 milliseconds** and exactly-once fault-tolerance guarantees.

Also since Spark 2.3, with a new low-latency processing model called Continuous Processing, we can achieve end-to-end latencies as low as **1 millisecond** with at-least-once guarantees.

There is an open-source Hortonworks Spark-Hbase connector package: 'com.hortonworks:shc-core:1.1.0-2.1-s_2.11'.

To ingest Datafram to HBase Catalog table is required with schema information. The below Catalog defines a schema for a HBase table with name as table1, row key as key and a number of columns (col1-col8). Note that the rowkey also has to be defined in details as a column (col0), which has a specific cf (rowkey).

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SQLContext, _}
import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase._
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import spark.sqlContext.implicits._

def catalog = s"""{
    |"table":{"namespace":"default", "name":"table1"},
    |"rowkey":"key",
    |"columns":{
      |"col0":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"key", "type":"string"},
      |"col1":{"cf":"cf1", "col":"col1", "type":"boolean"},
      |"col2":{"cf":"cf2", "col":"col2", "type":"double"},
      |"col3":{"cf":"cf3", "col":"col3", "type":"float"},
      |"col4":{"cf":"cf4", "col":"col4", "type":"int"},
      |"col5":{"cf":"cf5", "col":"col5", "type":"bigint"},
      |"col6":{"cf":"cf6", "col":"col6", "type":"smallint"},
      |"col7":{"cf":"cf7", "col":"col7", "type":"string"},
      |"col8":{"cf":"cf8", "col":"col8", "type":"tinyint"}
    |}
  |}""".stripMargin

df.writeStream.options(
  Map(HBaseTableCatalog.tableCatalog -> catalog, HBaseTableCatalog.newTable -> "5"))
  .outputMode("update")
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase")
  .start()
```

Refer to: https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc

Comment: Thank you!! 100 milliseconds per event?

Comment: Structured Streaming processes as series of small batch jobs, 100 milli seconds latency is for batch.

Answer (score 1):

Flume is built exactly for the purpose you want: to push data from one system to the other. Since you can configure it to have the batch size you want (which would be something really small if latency is all you care about) it should be as good as you can get. It already has a sink for HBase but if in the future you need to switch the storage the worst it can happen is that you have to implement the sink yourself.

Flink can also do what you want since you can also [configure it to be optimized for latency](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/dev/datastream_api.html#controlling-latency). However it has been built so that you could perform more elaborate transformations so I'd expect for it to be a little less performant than Flume, but there's nothing like benchmarking it yourself for your specific use case.